# Email All Rows in Single Email If Dates Match

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Today I tried to write a script which email the information about all upcoming arrivals for *todays* and *tomorrows* dates *in a single email*. However, my script send each booking details (i.e., if it does match conditional expression) (both for todays and tomorrows conditional expressions) in a separated email.

I'm a complete beginner in scripting with Goole Apps Script. I tried to search for "email array values google app script" and "all matching array values in email" but it hasn't shed new light on a stuck I'm with now.

Instead of this I want it (1) to check the column whether it matches todays and/or tomorrows date then (2) gather all booking details and afterwards (3) splitting them on today-arrivals and tomorrow-arrivals put it into a single electronic mail message.

Here is my source code:

```
/* Отправка уведомлений о предстоящих заездах на сегодня и на завтра. */
function NotifyUpcomingArrivals() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // Строка с первым бронированием для начала обработки.
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Количество строк с бронированиями для обработки.
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 18); // Охват столбцов для обработки ячеек, в данном случае с 1-го по 18-ый.
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Получить значение ячеек в каждой ячейке каждой строке в рамках столбцов, охваченных верхним кодом.
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var bookingNumber = [i+2];
        var todaysDate = new Date(); // Сегодняшняя дата.
        var tomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(1*24*3600*1000)); // Завтрашняя дата.
        var dayAfterTomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(2*24*3600*1000)); // Послезавтрашняя дата.
        var checkInDate = new Date(row[0]);
        var checkOutDate = new Date(row[1]);
        var formattedTodaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(tomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedDayAfterTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(dayAfterTomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var fullCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 14:00";
        var fullCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 12:00";
        var roomType = "«" + row[2] + "»";
        var numberOfGuests = row[3];
        var costPerNight = row[4] + " руб.";
        var prepaymentCost = row[8] + " руб.";
        var contactFullName = row[5];
        var contactPhone = row[6];
        var contactEmail = row[7];
        var bookingNotes = row[11];
        var reviewDummy = row[13];
        /* Здесь расчёт промежуточных переменных. */
        var differenceBetweenDays = Math.round(Math.abs((checkOutDate.getTime() - checkInDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
        var unpaidCost = (costPerNight*differenceBetweenDays)-prepaymentCost + " руб."; // Сумма, которую необходимо оплатить гостю по приезде.
        var bookingsListLink = "link";
        /* Здесь установка параметров отправителя. */
        var recipientEmail = "email1@address.com";
        var senderName = "Робот Руслана Селецкого (Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56)";
        var replyTo = "email2@address.com";
        var subject = "Сводка бронирований на" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + ") и на" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + ")";
            /* Сегодняшние заезды. */
            if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTodaysDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на сегодня, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
            var todaysArrivalsMessage = "Бронирования на" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + ")" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (строка № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nЦена за ночь: " + costPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + prepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + unpaidCost;
            // MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
            Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о сегодняшнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
            }
            /* Завтрашние заезды. */
            if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTomorrowsDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на завтра, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
            var tomorrowsArrivalsMessage = "\n" + "\nБронирования на" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + ")" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (строка № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nЦена за ночь: " + costPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + prepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + unpaidCost + "\n" + "\nПожалуйста, предупреди горничную о предстоящих заездах, а также сделай всё возможное, чтобы всё было готово по приезде гостей." + "\n" + "\n* Посмотреть полный список бронирований всегда можно тут: " + bookingsListLink + ".";
            // MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
            Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о завтрашнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
            }
            var message = todaysArrivalsMessage + tomorrowsArrivalsMessage;
            MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
            SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Показываем пользователю что изменения вступают в силу.
       }
}
```

How can I fix it to achieve desired results? Please, provide me with both helpful code examples as well as with useful reading for deeper understanding.

All problem-oriented help is at least strongly appreciated and rewarded by community.

**UPD № 1.** I did minor changes basing on @Afroman Makgalemela suggestion:

```
/* Отправка уведомлений о предстоящих заездах на сегодня и на завтра (с поправками чувака на Стаковерфлоу.ком). */
function NotifyUpcomingArrivals() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2; // Строка с первым бронированием для начала обработки.
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Количество строк с бронированиями для обработки.
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 18); // Охват столбцов для обработки ячеек, в данном случае с 1-го по 18-ый.
    var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Получить значение ячеек в каждой ячейке каждой строке в рамках столбцов, охваченных верхним кодом.
    /* Здесь установка параметров отправителя. */
    var message = undefined; 
    var subject = undefined;
    var recipientEmail = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru";
    var bookingsListLink = "http://bitly.com/b56bookingslist";
    var senderName = "Робот Руслана Селецкого (Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56)";
    var replyTo = "ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var bookingNumber = [i+2];
        var todaysDate = new Date(); // Сегодняшняя дата.
        var tomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(1*24*3600*1000)); // Завтрашняя дата.
        var dayAfterTomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(2*24*3600*1000)); // Послезавтрашняя дата.
        var checkInDate = new Date(row[0]);
        var checkOutDate = new Date(row[1]);
        var formattedTodaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(tomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedDayAfterTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(dayAfterTomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var formattedCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
        var fullCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 14:00";
        var fullCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 12:00";
        var roomType = "«" + row[2] + "»";
        var numberOfGuests = row[3];
        var costPerNight = row[4];
        var prepaymentCost = row[8];
        var formattedCostPerNight = costPerNight + " руб.";
        var formattedPrepaymentCost = prepaymentCost + " руб.";
        var contactFullName = row[5];
        var contactPhone = row[6];
        var contactEmail = row[7];
        var bookingNotes = row[11];
        var reviewDummy = row[13];
        /* Здесь расчёт промежуточных переменных. */
        var numberOfNights = Math.round(Math.abs((checkOutDate.getTime() - checkInDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
        var unpaidCost = (costPerNight*numberOfNights)-prepaymentCost;
        var formattedNumberOfNights = numberOfNights + " шт."; // Количество ночей проживания.
        var formattedUnpaidCost = unpaidCost + " руб."; // Сумма, которую необходимо оплатить гостю по приезде.
            /* Сегодняшние заезды. */
            if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTodaysDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на сегодня, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
            var todaysArrivalsMessage = "Бронирования с заездами" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + "):" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (см. строку № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nКоличество ночей: " + formattedNumberOfNights + "\nЦена за ночь: " + formattedCostPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + formattedPrepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + formattedUnpaidCost;
            Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о сегодняшнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
            }
            /* Завтрашние заезды. */
            if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTomorrowsDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на завтра, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
            var tomorrowsArrivalsMessage = "Бронирования с заездами" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + "):" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (см. строку № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nКоличество ночей: " + formattedNumberOfNights + "\nЦена за ночь: " + formattedCostPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + formattedPrepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + formattedUnpaidCost;
            Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о завтрашнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
            }
            var subject = "Сводка бронирований на" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + ") и на" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + ")";
            var messageBeginning = "Доброе утро,";
            var messageSignature = "Пожалуйста, предупреди горничную о предстоящих заездах, а также сделай всё возможное, чтобы абсолютно всё было готово по приезде гостей." + "\n" + "\n* Посмотреть полный список бронирований всегда можно тут: " + bookingsListLink + ".";
            var message = messageBeginning + "\n" + "\n" + todaysArrivalsMessage + "\n" + "\n" + tomorrowsArrivalsMessage + "\n" + "\n" + messageSignature;
            }
    // MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
    ui.alert("Тестирования механизма формирования уведомлений", "Тема письма:" + "\n" + "\n" + subject + "\n" + "\nТекст письма:" + "\n" + "\n" + message, ui.ButtonSet.OK);
    Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление с предстоящими заездами" + formattedTodaysDate + " и " + formattedTomorrowsDate + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Показываем пользователю что изменения вступают в силу.
}
```

Now it works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Just so you know the bitly URL points to a publicly accessible spreadsheet containing your clients telephone numbers and email addresses. Unless this is test data you might want to restrict access to that as soon as possible!

Comment: @samScholefield, Thank you sir. Privacy has always been a priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare message as a global var outside your for loop, and call the sendEmail also from outside the for loop. this -> data = dataRange.getValues(); groups by date, hence why your results for today and tomorrow are send separately.

```
 /* Отправка уведомлений о предстоящих заездах на сегодня и на завтра. */
    function NotifyUpcomingArrivals() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var startRow = 2; // Строка с первым бронированием для начала обработки.
        var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1; // Количество строк с бронированиями для обработки.
    var message = undefined, subject =undefined;

    var recipientEmail = "natalya@berdyanskaya56.ru";
 var bookingsListLink = "http://bitly.com/b56bookingslist";
            var senderName = "Робот Руслана Селецкого (Мини-гостиница Бердянская 56)";
            var replyTo = "ruslan@berdyanskaya56.ru";
        var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 18); // Охват столбцов для обработки ячеек, в данном случае с 1-го по 18-ый.
        var data = dataRange.getValues(); // Получить значение ячеек в каждой ячейке каждой строке в рамках столбцов, охваченных верхним кодом.
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
            var row = data[i];
            var bookingNumber = [i+2];
            var todaysDate = new Date(); // Сегодняшняя дата.
            var tomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(1*24*3600*1000)); // Завтрашняя дата.
            var dayAfterTomorrowsDate = new Date(todaysDate.getTime()+(2*24*3600*1000)); // Послезавтрашняя дата.
            var checkInDate = new Date(row[0]);
            var checkOutDate = new Date(row[1]);
            var formattedTodaysDate = Utilities.formatDate(todaysDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
            var formattedTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(tomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
            var formattedDayAfterTomorrowsDate = Utilities.formatDate(dayAfterTomorrowsDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
            var formattedCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
            var formattedCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy");
            var fullCheckInDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkInDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 14:00";
            var fullCheckOutDate = Utilities.formatDate(checkOutDate, "GMT+0300", "dd.MM.yyyy") + " в 12:00";
            var roomType = "«" + row[2] + "»";
            var numberOfGuests = row[3];
            var costPerNight = row[4] + " руб.";
            var prepaymentCost = row[8] + " руб.";
            var contactFullName = row[5];
            var contactPhone = row[6];
            var contactEmail = row[7];
            var bookingNotes = row[11];
            var reviewDummy = row[13];
            /* Здесь расчёт промежуточных переменных. */
            var differenceBetweenDays = Math.round(Math.abs((checkOutDate.getTime() - checkInDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));
            var unpaidCost = (costPerNight*differenceBetweenDays)-prepaymentCost + " руб."; // Сумма, которую необходимо оплатить гостю по приезде.


            subject = "Сводка бронирований на" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + ") и на" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + ")";
                /* Сегодняшние заезды. */
                if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTodaysDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на сегодня, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
                var todaysArrivalsMessage = "Бронирования на" + " сегодня (" + formattedTodaysDate + ")" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (строка № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nЦена за ночь: " + costPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + prepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + unpaidCost;
                // MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
                Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о сегодняшнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
                }
                /* Завтрашние заезды. */
                if (formattedCheckInDate == formattedTomorrowsDate && reviewDummy !== "–") { // Условное выражение, позволяющее отобрать бронирования с заездом на завтра, но кроме тех, которые уже были отменены гостями.
                var tomorrowsArrivalsMessage = "\n" + "\nБронирования на" + " завтра (" + formattedTomorrowsDate + ")" + "\n" + "\n" + contactFullName + " (строка № " + bookingNumber + ")" + "\nНомер: " + roomType + "\nТип размещения: " + numberOfGuests + "\nЦена за ночь: " + costPerNight + "\nВнесённый депозит: " + prepaymentCost + "\nОсталось взять по приезде: " + unpaidCost + "\n" + "\nПожалуйста, предупреди горничную о предстоящих заездах, а также сделай всё возможное, чтобы всё было готово по приезде гостей." + "\n" + "\n* Посмотреть полный список бронирований всегда можно тут: " + bookingsListLink + ".";
                // MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
                Logger.log("Отправлено уведомление о завтрашнем предстоящем заезде по бронированию № " + bookingNumber + " (" + contactFullName + ")" + " на " + recipientEmail + ".");
                }
                message += todaysArrivalsMessage + tomorrowsArrivalsMessage;

           }
 MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, subject, message, {name: senderName, replyTo: replyTo});
                SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Показываем пользователю что изменения вступают в силу.
    }
```

Comment: But how will I catch the bookings for today (`todaysDate = checkInDate`) and those for tomorrow (`tomorrowsDate = checkOutDate`)?

Comment: I've already use `var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 18);var data = dataRange.getValues();`. What should I change to make all values be put into a single email?

Comment: Will refactor your code, ... obviously not checking the functionality,...

Comment: In the top comment I just meant to say that if I move both `todaysArrivalsMessage` and `tomorrowsArrivalsMessage` outside of loops inside them will be nothing in total. Or maybe I didn't catch your advice? Please, explain in detail.

Comment: What do you mean by `// You don't actually need a for loop, but would consume more time to fix this`? In you example you didn't delete conditional expressions.

Comment: check update! aslo, move out the subject from the for loop. Unfortunately, done for the day. Goodluck!

Comment: Yes I did. Please check the update. However, If two rows in Google Spreadsheet match loops' condition, how do I make it be written in email? What I exactly do mean is `var email = matchingConditionValue1 + matchingConditionValue2 + matchingConditionValue3 + ... + matchingConditionValueN`. All condition-matching values are string.